# Edge Browser: Link From PDF Not Opening a New PDF File

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, adobe, microsoft-edge, acrobat

I installed an adobe acrobat extension in Edge browser. My link is relative path. I set up all these options with this extension:
[image]

[image]

In my PDF file, the embed link is a button.
After the click, it did not open a PDF file in Edge, but works fine in Chrome and Opera. What do I do to make it work in Edge?

(UPDATE)

This is how Opera and Google Chrome show my URL after I click a button in the PDF, which opens a PDF file. 
//example.azurewebsites.net/CANGC/Process/off-site-facility-management/6_1-Chemistry/Step-Descriptions/6-1-1/6-1-1-1.pdf

This is how Edge shows the URL after the click, which cannot locate the file.

//example.azurewebsites.net/CANGC/Process/off-site-facility-management/6_1-Chemistry/Flow-Chart/6.1%20Ultrasonic%20Chemistry%20Management/2.%20Process%20Design/2b.%20Step%20Descriptions/1%20-%20Chemical%20Inventory/6-1-1-1.pdf

Edge rewrote the URL longer, forcing the path wrong.

What's funny is that I put the same URL into the Edge Browser, which opens that PDF file. The extensions do not solve my problem. Is there another solution out there?

Comment: Do you mean that a link button in PDF can't open the link in Edge? Which version of Edge and Chrome do you use? Have you tried to disable Adobe extension and use Edge inner PDF viewer to see if it can open the link? And if possible, you can provide a sample pdf file so that we can have a test.

Comment: @YuZhou, Yes, the link button is in PDF. I want this link to open a pdf file.  I used the latest ones (Firefox (version 107.0.1), Opera (version 93.0.0), and Google Chrome (version 108.0.5).  

I tested the exact link; Firefox and Chrome opened the file. 
Here's the error message from Edge:
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  

Why do Firefox and Chrome recognize this URL path and Edge does not?

Comment: If it opens in Edge but doesn't open in Adobe extension, it's the extension's issue which doesn't have good support for Edge. I suggest that you can contact Adobe to see if they can provide any help. You can go to [Adobe Help Center](https://helpx.adobe.com/support.dc.html) to seek for help.

Comment: @YuZhou I have visited the adobe community. Getting an answer is tough. I think I should also reach out to the extension creator.

Comment: Yes, of course. You can also provide feedback about the issue in the extension's feedback hub: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cv0A5.png.